# Apply() Method's First Parameter Args

Tags: javascript

```
GAME = {};

GAME[1] = {
    test: 1,
    test2: 2
}
GAMELENGTH = (Math.max.apply(Math.max, Object.keys(GAME))) + 1;
GAMELENGTH2 = (Math.max.apply(Math.apply, Object.keys(GAME))) + 1;

GAMELENGTH3 = (Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(GAME))) + 1;

console.log(GAMELENGTH);
console.log(GAMELENGTH2);
console.log(GAMELENGTH3);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agx85sba/2/

What exactly am I supposed to use as the first parameter for `apply()`? As all these different `GAMELENGTH`'s have the same outcome but are taking in different parameters.

Comment: I tend to use `null` myself in these instances. It's the value of `this`.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). It’s whatever the `this` should be.

Comment: I tend to use 0, it's shorter.

Comment: Yeah, I've read the docs I just don't understand how `Math.apply` being sent as a parameter it has no value associated with it.

Comment: Here is an example on jsfiddle to help you understand where I'm coming from: http://jsfiddle.net/agx85sba/4/

I a applying `test` as a function to `GAMELENGTH4`, and returning `10 - data`, but as you can see it's still returning 2, when it should be returning `8`.  What `apply()` does is obviously different then what I think it does. I obviously don't get it.

I wonder if there is an example at how the first parameter in `apply() `can be used. That might help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`
>
> **thisArg**
>
> The value of `this` provided for the call to `fun`. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

---

For your use-case it does not matter. The actual implementation of `Math.max` may not care about `this`.

You use `apply` to get the maximum of a list of values without the need to write them all to the function call (`Math.max(1,2,3,4,5)` vs `var list = [1,2,3,4,5]; Math.max.apply(null, list)`).

Comment: Voted up, but take `GAMELENGTH2 = (Math.max.apply(Math.apply, Object.keys(GAME))) + 1;` for example. 'Math.apply' is being sent as a parameter, but that has no value associated with it, so how is `this` still being passed?

Comment: What do you mean by *how is `this` still being passed*? `Math.apply` has something assigned (the apply-function) and would be `this` inside the function you applied it to.

Comment: So in the first parameter, there is no data being passed, it's just a function that will apply it to the array in the 2nd parameter?